# Scaffolding for Visual Studio 2015 or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Does a feature exist for Visual Studio 2015 that does reasonable scaffolding for ASP.NET MVC?  What I mean by "reasonable" is this:

- DateTime fields are generated as Date drop downs (or Time).
- ID References to foreign keys are dropdowns listing data from other tables, rather than just text entry fields.
- Lists of items provide paging of some sort

P.S.  I know about right-clicking on Controller and Add/New Scaffolded Item..., but it suffers from all the problems mentioned above.

Comment: That's very custom functionality, I wouldn't expect any automated scaffolding to do that.  A one-off plugin for Visual Studio which does each of those things individually and on-demand would be pretty cool I suppose.  But personally I'd be pretty annoyed if the out-of-the-box scaffolding did these things automatically, since there's no guarantee that these fields *should* behave in this custom manner.

Comment: I haven't done it but from what I can gather it's just templates so it's able to be changed or extended. Although, I think I've seen the second bullet functionality be default. Are you mass scaffolding or doing it individually?

Comment: @David Honestly for scaffolding admin views, i don't care how it works/looks, as long as an admin user can go there and change data.  As it stands currently with the built-in scaffolding, my admin users would be lost. I just don't want to write custom code to address these tables.  Perhaps there is a product that does this.